# Add HTML file with CSS to another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have an **`index.html`** file, which is supposed to be the homepage of a website. On the homepage, I want to include a product configurator (let's call it **`config.html`**), which I have separately coded. Both **`index.html`** and **`config.html`** have their own separate CSS stylesheets. I'm also using Bootstrap in **`index.html`** and jquery in config.html.

Is there a way to embed **`config.html`** into **`index.html`** (the configurator onto the website homepage) without messing up the code?

I've tried just copying and pasting **`config.html`** into the **`index.html`** code, and the configurator CSS into the main website CSS, but it doesn't work.

Sorry if I'm not being clear enough, but I hope you get what I mean! I'm a complete beginner at HTML and a friend recommended me this website for additional help.

Comment: There are many frameworks available (like Angular) that makes it very easy to accomplish just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="import" href="url of your file">
```

this must be in head section.

you can also add a html file in div section, like.

```
<div w3-include-html="h1.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, try to add some code so we have a better understanding, however, you should be able to add `config.html` code to `index.html` with no need to have different pages. One way will be to put everything you have inside `config.html body` inside a new `<div>` in `index.html` or you can make use of `<iframe>` more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). There are many ways around. Try and make use of [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to embed the two HTML documents for instance:

If your index.html file has a div tag with the class homepage.

```
<div class="homepage">
 <!--Here am assuming that this is the content inside your 
    index.html-->
</div>
```

Whatever info is there in your homepage you can add it within the div tag of class "homepage" then add a second div tag which will represent your config.html document as shown here:

```
<div class="config.html">
   **The contents of your config file will appear here once 
     you have added the Jquery snippet below.**
</div>
```

Then add this javascript snippet to embed the two pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function)(){

    **Jquery will load the contents of your config.html within 
      the div tag in your index.html file**

    $(".config").load("config.html"); //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT

  });

<script/>
```

Next time please provide some code to make this a bit simpler to explain.